# How to change the language in which official Ubuntu documentation (online) is displayed?

Tags: documentation, ubuntu-website

The official Ubuntu documentation is available at https://help.ubuntu.com/. Curiously, it automatically displays the content in the locale that the user's browser provides, without any option to change the language. For example, currently when I open the URL https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/cups.html, it's automatically in German, but I'd like to read it in English. How may I do it?

Answer (score 2):

As of 2017-10-12, there is no nice way via the user interface.  There is a bug report asking for a way, [bug #1532537](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-docs/+bug/1532537).  Please add yourself to the list of affected people.

**WORKAROUND**

You can call the webpage with the language of your choice by appending `.<language code>` to the URL.  Examples:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/index.html.en
- https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/index.html.fr
- https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/index.html.de

Answer (score 1):

- As workaround, Firefox have a nice addon that let switch locale quickly.

  > **[Quick Accept-Language Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/quick-accept-language-switc/?src=search)** by Dan Callahan
  >
  > Provides a quick way of changing the HTTP Accept-Language header so you can view and test websites with a different locale.

  [image: Quick Accept-Language Switcher]
- Another one which seems better as you can set it permanently per site basis.

  > **[HeaderControlRevived](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/headercontrolrevived/?src=search)** by Torvin
  >
  > Provides control over HTTP headers (User-Agent, Referer and Accept-Language) on a per-site basis.

  [image: HeaderControlRevived]